Is there a way to make event listeners on web extensions always be ready?
I recently switched from Firefox to Opera. In Firefox, when the browser is in full-screen mode, if the user hovers the mouse at the top of the screen, it temporarily exits full-screen mode and re-enters it once the mouse stops hovering at the top. Opera does not have this functionality, so I attempted to add it myself with an extension.
manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "name": "Opera Extensions — Getting Started",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at":     "document_end",
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ],
    "description": "Sample extension for the “Making your first extension” article",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "windows"
  ]
}

main.js
console.log("The extension is up and running");

function isFullScreen() {
  return (window.fullScreen) ||
    (window.innerWidth === screen.width && window.innerHeight === screen.height);
}

function enterFullScreen() {
  if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) { // Firefox
    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) { // Chrome, Safari and Opera
    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) { // IE/Edge
    document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function exitFullScreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { // Firefox
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { // Chrome, Safari and Opera
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { // IE/Edge
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}

function toggleAddressAndTabBars() {
  if (isFullScreen()) {
    exitFullScreen();
  } else {
    enterFullScreen();
  }
}

const topArea = document.createElement('div');
topArea.style.position = 'fixed';
topArea.style.top = '0';
topArea.style.left = '0';
topArea.style.width = '100%';
topArea.style.height = '5px'; 
topArea.style.zIndex = '9999';
topArea.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; //only yellow for testing will be transparent
document.body.appendChild(topArea);

topArea.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleAddressAndTabBars);

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (!isFullScreen()) {
    enterFullScreen();
  }
});



First of all, my code enters full-screen mode by clicking. This was done because it seems that it won't work with the normal F11 key.
After you enter full-screen mode by clicking, if you hover to the top of the screen, it will exit full-screen mode. However, once you move the mouse down, it won't re-enter full-screen mode. The toggle function seems to stop working after it has been called once. Any help would be appreciated.


Add mouseleave listener. 2) Remove isFullScreen() function and replace the check with if (document.fullscreenElement) { 3) remove all code that uses prefixed values (moz, webkit, ms) as it's for really ancient browsers.

